# Command to Move Mouse Pointer to Other Screen

Tags: 14.04, mouse

I have a dual monitor configuration in Ubuntu.

What is a bash command which will send my mouse pointer into the other screen (without having to manually move the mouse pointer myself)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can install the `xdotool` utility and then move the mouse to a given screen and x and y position, eg:

```
xdotool mousemove --screen 1 10 10
```

If your 2 screens are actually one large virtual screen (xinerama mode) you dont use --screen but give a very large x value.

Comment: That gives an error

# xdotool mousemove --screen 1 0 0
Responds with:
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  41 (X_WarpPointer)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x18
  Serial number of failed request:  20
  Current serial number in output stream:  22

(OK, its not an Ubundu box, its a Raspberry, but I hoped it was the same...)

Comment: The raspberry pi graphics setup seems to be very different to that for a normal pc, so I don't think I can help. Perhaps the second screen is not number 1 but some other number. `xrandr` or `xdpyinfo` will list the screen numbers. You might get more help on [raspberrypi.stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/).